# Can I have show two different approaches in single thesis, regarding the same topic?

Tags: thesis, masters

I am doing research on Security Patterns. In First 6 month i was working on Formalization of Security Patterns. I have extended a approach for formalization of Security Patterns. Subsequently, in the next 6 month i did research on Selection of Appropriate security patterns. 
Normally, The structure of thesis

1. Introduction
2. Related Work
3. Proposed Work
4. Implementation
5. Result , Conclusion and Future.

I am confused in this. 
I have different implementation and result respectively for Formalization and Selection techniques. 
My Thesis Content will look like

1. Introduction
2. Related Work
3. Formalization(Proposed Work,Implementation and Result).
4. Selection(Proposed Work, Implementation and Result).
5. Conclusion.

Can i have two different result and implementation in a thesis. It is acceptable or not? 
Thesis is for Master Degree.

Comment: What did your advisor say?

Comment: I am from India. My advisor doesn't actually care. He wont even read it..... I want to confirm it because i want to apply for Ph.d in Good foreign Universities.

Comment: What do you mean by two different approaches? You mean theory and practice? Or you mean two sorts of theoretical   formalizations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is totally normal and reasonable to do more than one type of work on a problem, and to report it in a structure like the one that you have sketched.  Just make sure that your explanation follows a coherent narrative (e.g., how does your work on selection follow from your work on formalization) and it will be fine.

Comment: I'd like to add that the coherent narrative can be explicitly outlined (and justified) in the introduction section. The OP should be happy about that, because it provides them with even more content to write about - content that will reflect positively on the OP, because it shows that they have put some thought into their document and checked what is appropriate for their particular problem rather than just copying a standard structure. (At least in environments where a good presentation has a positive influence on the overall grade/judgement of the thesis.)